# How to define lazy AND

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lazy-evaluation

I have defined the following macros:

```
(defmacro ~lazy (expression)
  `(lambda ()
     ,@expression))

(defgeneric force~ (value)
  (:method (value)
    value)
  (:method ((value function))
    (funcall value)))

(defmacro ~~ (expression)
  `(~lazy (force~ ,expression)))
```

[...]
The following macro defines a generic function of name 'NAME' with some standard methods defined. This should work like 'REDUCE' and force all lazy values on the way while returning a lazy value when it even once encountered a lazy value and a nonlazy value otherwise (signified by the macro beginning and ending with '~').

```
(defmacro ~lazy-reduce~ (name reduce-fun (arg-var args-var)
                         &body methods)
  (let ((first (gensym "first")))
    `(defgeneric ,name (,arg-var ,args-var)
       ,@(append
          (if (not (member `(,arg-var (,args-var cons))
                           methods
                           :key #'car
                           :test #'equal))
              `((:method (,arg-var (,args-var cons))
                  (let ((,first (first ,args-var)))
                    (if (functionp ,first)
                        (~~ (,reduce-fun (force~ ,first)
                                         (force~
                                          (,name ,arg-var
                                                 (rest ,args-var)))))
                        (,name (,reduce-fun ,arg-var ,first)
                               (rest ,args-var)))))))
          (if (not (member `((,arg-var function)
                             ,args-var)
                           methods
                           :key #'car
                           :test #'equal))
              `((:method ((,arg-var function)
                          ,args-var)
                  (~~ (,name (force~ ,arg-var)
                             ,args-var))))))
       ,@(mapcar (lambda (method)
                   (cons :method method))
                 methods))))
```

Now I define ~_AND~ like this:

```
(~lazy-reduce~ ~_and~ and (val vals)
   (((val null)
     vals)
    nil)
   ((val (vals null))
    val))
```

Calling

```
(~_and~ t (list 2))
```

works just fine and returns '2', as expected, yet

```
(force~ ~_and~ t (list (~ 2)))
```

returns just 'T'.

I have no idea why that is and it prevents me from concisely defining '~FIND-IF'.

Comment: I think the code does not look maintenance friendly. I would propose to get rid of the APPEND, create a predicate to detect the method presence based on the arglist and to write generator functions for the code. Use 'Functional abstraction'.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look into that, especially since I need this functionality more often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error: the first method of ~_AND~ looks like this:

```
(:method (val (vals cons))
 (let ((first (first vals)))
   (if (functionp first)
       (~~ (and (force~ first)
                (force~ (~_and~ val (rest vals)))))
       (~_and~ (and val first)
               (rest vals)))))
```

(This can be seen by MACROEXPAND-1 on the given definition of ~_AND~)

That means that the shown call was evaluated (roughly) as

```
(and (force~ (~ 2))
     T)
```

This returns 'T', as seen.